# Java web application gets slower if running a day

Tags: java, performance, wicket, eclipselink

I am developing a java web application using the apache wicket framework and Eclipselink with PostgreSQL for OR mapping.

If i run the application (on localhost or on a remote server) everything is fast and useable. There are only five users at the moment. After about a day, some parts of the application start getting slow. Especially pages that use data from the database and an autocomplete function which uses data from OWL files. Static pages load quite fast.

Any ideas how to find the problem?

**EDIT:**

Thanks for your reply. The problem seems to be the memory usage generated by the sessions. That explains why i can't reproduce the issue on my local machine with only one user. A quick fix for me was increasing the heap size (-Xmx and -Xms) when starting Tomcat. Now i will go deeper into the wicket pages and find the memory-consuming models.

Comment: So...why not just restart the webapp every night? I know, it doesn't FIX the problem but it does MITIGATE it.

Comment: It is running on a virtual server with 1GB of RAM. Tomcat Status shows the following: "Free memory: 29.45 MB Total memory: 125.93 MB Max memory: 125.93 MB". The top command tells me, that java uses about 30-40% of the memory. These values are constant over time.

Comment: @josh: i am restarting the server every day already, but i want to avoid this ;-)

Comment: Profile + don't neglect to detail your stack i.e. your app server is?

Comment: GC logs? Tomcat status is not reliable source.

Comment: Enable verbosegc to see if you're returning smaller amounts to the heap over time? (Which would indicate a leak.)

Comment: See below for my answer, but with wicket: detach detach detach!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wicket demands some pretty solid coding practices around the "weight" of the serialized page.  Serialized pages get stored in the Session and, if you fail to detach any class-level models, the data gets serialized, too.  Before I realized this, I saw Session sizes approaching several hundred MB because I was serializing half my database queries!

So, a few things that might help:

Override your session store to warn you when you modify if the session is too big.

```
 public class CustomSessionStore extends SecondLevelCacheSessionStore {

    @Override
    public void setAttribute(Request request, String name, Object value) {
        super.setAttribute(request, name, value);

        if (Session.get().getSizeInBytes() > SESSION_WARN_LIMIT) {
            log.warn("Session Size is {} bytes", Session.get().getSizeInBytes());
        }
    }
 }
```

Make sure you detach your models:

```
public class MyPage extends WebPage {

    IModel<HeavyDataObject> heavyModel;

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        if (heavyModel != null)
            heavyModel.detach();
    }

}
```

Use the wicket developer tools to monitor various data sizes/stores while the application is running.  The maven dependency is `org.apache.wicket wicket-devutils`

Hope that helps!

Comment: Would you need to declare heavyModel as a LoadableDetachableModel?

Comment: All models are "detachable."  LoadableDetachableModel is a (commonly used) convenience model that, when used properly, drops the heavy stuff on `detach()` while still providing the heavy stuff the next time it is requested.

Comment: Where should i integrate the CustomSessionStore?

Comment: And i am using PropertyModel and Compoundpropertymodel but as local variables and not as members of the page classes. Do i have do detach the models when they are local too?

Comment: Apologies for the delay.  `Application.newSessionStore()` is where you can use your custom version.  `PropertyModel` and `CompoundPropertyModel` generally point to some, often heavy, object.  If said object is stored as a class-level variable in the `Page` or a `Component`, then that would be a big problem.

Comment: Explicitly detaching of models doesn't need to be done if the model is binded to a Component (e.g. by passing it to the constructor, explicitly setting it using Component#setDefaultModel()), if properly binded they should get detached automatically when the component gets detached.

The only times I need to explicitly detach the models is when a component handles more than one model.

Comment: True.  If memory serves, this is only an issue if you're using models as class-level variables.  In both cases, the model object (and associated loading information) will be serialized, but only the Component's Model will be detached automatically.  That's the most common use case, so people forget that, as your pages become complex and you make more use of Model objects outside of the default Model, you need to make sure they all get detached.

Answer (score 1):

[jVisualVM](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html) is your friend.

If you are using eclipse to develop your application, then try considering [Memory Analysis Tool](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) plugin and a nice tutorial [here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseMemoryAnalyser/article.html).

- Check memory uses of your application first
- Then consider request dispatching time...

These can be easy start to find the bottleneck.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [Yourkit](http://www.yourkit.com/) in the past, which is a useful tool for profiling an application.

Answer (score 0):

Well, having a tool like [dynaTrace](http://www.dynatrace.com) helps make things easier because it can more immediately show you the layer(s) of your application that are having issues with performance.

However, in lieu of not having that, I would look at your memory and CPU usage on your system to see if/when it spikes. Look at memory usage over time. See if you can see what the garbage collector is doing and how much is freed up after it runs. Perhaps you have a memory leak, objects left on the heap through some obscure "link" that keeps them alive. (Also take a look at Collections and ArrayLists and regular arrays and what not. Those can often be the source of a leak. Are you creating too many Strings and doing tons of "+" concatenation instead of using StringBuffer?

Also, is it just certain parts of your application that are slow? Or the whole thing? Perhaps you need more memory on the heap to run better? Perhaps you need to check your DB to see if it recommends indexes or more efficient queries, etc.

Another thought...and I don't mean this in a bad way....did you load test the application on your system or another system before putting it into "production" or wherever your problem lies?

Just a few ideas of things to look for. Just remember to tune one thing at a time and see if that made a difference. Tuning too many things at once doesn't help you to know what really fixed the problem.

But honestly...I'd look into a tool like dynaTrace or other (I know dynaTrace because we use it at our company). If nothing else it gives you a better direction to pursue when trying to troubleshoot.

Oh, and be careful about if you are using the HttpSession to store a LOT of variables. You can quickly run out of memory if you do that.

Answer (score 0):

This definitely sounds like memory to me. It sounds like your machine, specifically the JVM, is swapping. There's nothing worse than a JVM swapping.

25MB of free memory is "nothing" today, especially out of 1GB.

The reason I say this is simply because with 5 users, it is unlikely that they are the cause of your problems. You could be doing a LOT of web traffic, and storing stuff is truly awful data structures, and performing some O(n^2) algorithms on data accumulated from the traffic of your 5 users.

That's all possible. It's just really unlikely.

With the tight resources on your machine, and the voracious appetites for memory that Java, and other things, have today, I'm more inclined given what little we know to point to the machine thrashing away in need of more memory.